# War deployment using Tomcat7 Web Application Manager

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to override my previous project.war which points to localhost:8080/project file using the web uploader.

If I change the name of the file to project2.war & upload it, the url then becomes localhost:8080/project2 which I don't want.

If I leave the new build name project.war, then I am unable to deploy the new build as it says "The project.war already exists).

If I undeploy the project.war, I can deploy the new project.war however, I need to wait for the upload to finish.

That means, the tomcat app will be unavailable for a few minutes after it is deployed.

How can I override the previous .war file without any downtime so that the users will only notice a 5-6 second deployment delay?

Thank you.

Comment: Tomcat can only map a given URL to a given WAR, AFAIK.  If you want the same path I don't see anyway around restarting Tomcat.  Would there be anything wrong with restarting in the middle of the night when few users are around?

Comment: Do you want to get up in the middle of the night for me? :)